# if $\int_{0}^{\infty}g(x)dx=-\infty$ then $g(\infty)<=0$?

Tags: integration, improper-integrals, infinity

if $\int_{0}^{\infty}g(x)dx=-\infty$ and $g(x)$ is a continues function.

then by which theorem one can conclude that $g(\infty)<=0$?

Comment: What do you mean by "$g(\infty)$"?

Comment: @lord-shark-the-unknown    $lim g(x)$ in infinity

Comment: $\lim_{x\to\infty}g(x)$ may not exist.

Answer (score 6):

No, consider for example
$$
g(x)=\sin x-\frac{1}{4}.
$$